# Search All order with email Id in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am a newbie to `woocommerce`, I want to create a template in wordpress in which when a customer enters `email ID`, after submitting this email ID, the system would show all order given by that email id

The question is `How can I search All order list by that email ID ?`

Comment: Yep that is but if I want to show for guest users then how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code :
Here have used a shortcode to call and display the output. So user `[wdm__customer_orders]` shortcode and replace the Comments with your data.

```
add_shortcode('wdm__customer_orders', 'wmd_my_custom_function');
function wmd_my_custom_function(){
  $user_email=/*email id of your choice for which you want to list out orders*/;
  $user_info=get_user_by( 'email', $user_email );
  $user_id=$user_info->ID;
  print_r(get_meta_values('_customer_user',$user_id));
}

function get_meta_values( $key = '', $user_id = '' ) {

    global $wpdb;

    if( empty( $key ) )
        return;

    $r = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( "
        SELECT pm.post_id FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} pm
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} p ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        WHERE pm.meta_key = '%s' AND  pm.meta_value = '%s'
    ", $key,$user_id ) );

    return $r;
}
```

Use this function to retrieve the list of order ids for a user.

This is for test purpose you should later change and integrate as required for you.